# Getting warning in console for ag grid react while navigating between screens

Tags: ag-grid-react

Getting warning while navigating between screens in ag grid.

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
in HeaderCellComp (created by HeaderRowComp)
in div (created by HeaderRowComp)
in HeaderRowComp (created by HeaderRowContainerComp)
in div (created by HeaderRowContainerComp)
in div (created by HeaderRowContainerComp)
in HeaderRowContainerComp (created by GridHeaderComp)
in div (created by GridHeaderComp)
in GridHeaderComp (created by GridBodyComp)
in div (created by GridBodyComp)
in GridBodyComp (created by GridComp)
in ForwardRef(TabGuardCompRef)
in ForwardRef(TabGuardCompRef) (created by GridComp)
in div (created by GridComp)
in div (created by GridComp)
in GridComp (created by AgGridReactUi)
in div (created by AgGridReactUi)
in AgGridReactUi (created by AgGridReact)
in AgGridReact (at DataGridComponent.js:200)
in div (at DataGridComponent.js:193)
```

I am using custom UI for `headerComponent` and for some columns.

Tried looking a lot of links and documents but I am not sure how to trace this back to ag-grid issue or my code issue , the stack eventually traces back to my code to `DataGridComponent` which is my wrapper for the grid.

Looking at the error looks like, somewhere the grid is trying to update a cell post it is destroyed. Or is it anything else ?

Thanks & regards,
Susheel Tickoo